# get all links that avalibale in a website using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, url, selenium-webdriver

are there are any way using python to get all links in the web site not only in the web page ? I tried this code but that's give me only links in the web page

```
import urllib2
import re

#connect to a URL
website = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')

#read html code
html = website.read()

#use re.findall to get all the links
links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)

print links
```

Comment: What do you mean with "all links in the web site not only in the web page"? Do you mean every link that is contained in any html page that is stored on www.example.com?

Comment: yes that's what i mean

Comment: You cannot do that. You may not even have access to all html pages. However you can recursivly visit the links you gathered (if they also point to www.exmaple.com or if they are relative links) and get all links from there. However this may not be "all links", e.g. if there is a page example.com/jfifjfi where no link points to you will not be able to visit that page.

Comment: the website links are puplic

Comment: You could also take a look at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) which does all you want. It may be overkill and you will probably not learn as much, but if you want it simply to be done it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Visit recursively the links you have gathered and scrap these pages too:

```
import urllib2
import re

stack = ['http://www.example.com/']
results = []

while len(stack) > 0:

    url = stack.pop()
    #connect to a URL
    website = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    #read html code
    html = website.read()

    #use re.findall to get all the links
    # you should not only gather links with http/ftps but also relative links
    # you could use beautiful soup for that (if you want <a> links)
    links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)

    result.extend([link in links if is_not_relative_link(link)])

    for link in links:
        if link_is_valid(link): #this function has to be written
            stack.push(link)
```

Comment: if link_is_valid(link): #this function has to be written
NameError: name 'link_is_valid' is not defined

Comment: Yes. Thus I wrote "#this function has to be written" as a comment. You must check if a) you already visited that link b) if you even want to visit that link (i.e. if it links to the page you want to visit "example.com" or if it links to e.g. wikipedia) c) if you can visit it (currently you are getting ftp links, I don't think urllib2 can handle them?).